# $[F(\alpha+\beta):F(\beta)]=[F(\alpha):F(\beta)]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This is a natural question which confused me a lot. I think generally it is true but I have no idea how to prove it. Also, can anyone raise any counter-example?

The question follows from a problem from Topics in Algebra by Herstein.

The problem is show that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{5}$  is algebraic over $Q$ of degree 6.

If I can prove the proposition $[F(\alpha+\beta):F(\beta)]=[F(\alpha):F(\beta)]$, then I can solve this question. However, now it seems impossible to do so.

Comment: Are you implying that $\beta \in F(\alpha)$?

Comment: @Arthur No. To let the question be more concrete, you can let $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$ and $\beta=5^$(one over three)

Comment: To define the degree of a field extension such as $[K:F]$, you have to have $F$ being a subfield of $K$.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson Alright. Get your point.

Answer (score 3):

We can show this quickly by just showing that $F(\alpha+\beta)=F(\alpha)$, as field extensions over $F(\beta)$.

We first show that $\alpha\in F(\alpha+\beta)$. As $F(\alpha+\beta)$ contains $\beta$ by being an extension over $F(\beta)$, $\alpha+\beta-\beta=\alpha\in F(\alpha+\beta)$.

A symmetric argument holds for the other direction.

Comment: Well..Why $F(\alpha+\beta)$ contains $\beta$?

Comment: If it doesn't, you can't define $[F(\alpha + \beta):F(\beta)]$.

Answer (score 3):

Counter-example:
$F=\mathbb{Q}$, $\alpha=\sqrt2$ and $\beta= \sqrt3$. We have 
$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2+\sqrt3):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3)]=2,$
but $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3)]$ is not defined.